# goroutine running with unexpectedly with unexpected values

Tags: go

I'm using the holidays to create a little test for a simple file system "database" (instead of a full-blown relational database).
The "table locks" are implemented using goroutines. These tables each have their own worker and are identified by their worker ID.
Weirdly, my demo reliably produces an error where I'm having trouble tracing the execution path that leads to a segfault.

There's a branch right in the beginning of the loop that handles deletions (`req.f == nil`) and skips the rest of the loop. Still, the code at the bottom of the loop runs with `req.f ==nil`. Also, it's unclear to me why a request with `f == nil` should even be there; the only place it's created with `f == nil` is from inside the cleanup function.

I'm puzzled. How is the goroutine executed when `f == nil`? Why is there an immediate cleanup request?

Here's the relevant code:

```
type workId uint64

type workFunc func()

type workReq struct {
  wId workId
  // set to nil to delete from list
  f *workFunc
}

const workCacheTimeout = time.Second * 5

func workRunner(wId workId, fc chan workFunc) {
  for f := range fc {
    f()
  }
}

for req := range c {
log.Println("req1", req)
  if req.f == nil {
    n, ok := workers[req.wId]
    if ok {
      close(n.work)
      delete(workers, req.wId)
    }

log.Println("deleted", req)
    continue
  }
log.Println("req2", req)

  n, ok := workers[req.wId]
  if ! ok {
    n.work = make(chan workFunc)
    n.cleanupTimer = time.AfterFunc(workCacheTimeout, func () {
      c <- workReq{req.wId, nil}
    })

    workers[req.wId] = n

    go workRunner(req.wId, n.work)
  }
log.Println("req3", req)

  go func() {
log.Println("req4", req)
    n.cleanupTimer.Reset(workCacheTimeout)
    n.work <- *req.f
  }()
}
```

The output:

```
2022/12/25 11:51:14 req1 {650304 0xc0000a71e0}
2022/12/25 11:51:14 req2 {650304 0xc0000a71e0}
2022/12/25 11:51:14 req3 {650304 0xc0000a71e0}
2022/12/25 11:51:14 req1 {650304 <nil>}
2022/12/25 11:51:14 deleted {650304 <nil>}
2022/12/25 11:51:14 n {0xc0004a9e60 0xc000452c30}
2022/12/25 11:51:14 req4 {650304 <nil>}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference 
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x64e405]
goroutine 4715 [running]:
main.handleWorkChan.func2()
        /redacted/dir_sync.go:62 +0x125
```

Comment: I suspect that [this](https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) will answer your question. You have a [race condition](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) because `req` may be reassigned (by the `for req := range c`) before it's used in the goroutine (meaning `req` no longer contains what you think it does).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Brits in the comments on the question, the error lies within the scopes of the anonymous functions.

Both use `req` and `n` from the loop's scope which is subject to change.
The solution mentioned in the [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) works..

```
  go func(req workReq) {
    n.cleanupTimer.Reset(workCacheTimeout)
    n.work <- *req.f
  }(req)
```

.. but I've found it prettier to move the code inside the loop to a new function "handleWorkReq" and call that from inside the loop:

```
func handleWorkReq(req workReq) {
  if req.f == nil {
...
}

..

for req := range c {
  handleWorkReq(req)
}
```

That more "naturally" uses the scope of the function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi, bot. yes, my anser is lacking. i wanted to get out a 'better than nothing' rather than a good explanation because a well thought-out answer takes more time to create than i'm willing to invest atm.